# Push Notifications when app is closed

Tags: android, notifications, push

Do you know if is it possible to receive notifications from google cloud message when the application is fully closed?

I know if it's open or in background yes, but can it be programmed any way in order to receive them?

**EDIT:**

I continue without receiving notifications when the app is closed.

I attached the code in case I have an error and I am not watching it.

MANIFEST

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.frab"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
android:minSdkVersion="14"
android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.frab.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<permission
android:name="com.frab.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

<application
android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
<activity
android:name="com.frab.MainActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>

<receiver
android:name=".GGMBroadcastReceiver"
android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
<category android:name="com.something" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

BROADCAST RECEIVER

```
package com.something;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.activities.SignIn;
import com.google.android.gcm.GCMBaseIntentService;
import com.objects.Globals;

public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {
private static final String TAG = "GGM <-----> FRAB";
private Bundle extras;

public GCMIntentService() {
super(Globals.SENDER_ID);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Log.d(TAG, "terminando servicio");
}

@Override
protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
Log.i(TAG, "onRegistered: registrationId=" + registrationId);
}

@Override
protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
Log.i(TAG, "onUnregistered: registrationId = " + registrationId);
}
@Override
protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent data) {
extras = data.getExtras();
String message = extras.getString("msg");
Log.d("******", message);
sendNotification(message);
}

@Override
protected void onError(Context arg0, String errorId) {
Log.e(TAG, "onError: errorId = " + errorId);
}    
}

package com.something;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;

public class GGMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
// Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(), GCMIntentService.class.getName());
// Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
}
```

When the app is open : **OK**

When the app is in background : **Ok**

When the app is closed forcefully by the user : **notifications don't arrive**

What is the problem?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @ user3757628 : How did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 23):

Yes, it is possible 'to receive notifications from google cloud message when the application is fully closed'.

Infact, A broadcast receiver is the mechanism GCM uses to deliver messages.
You need to have implement a [BroadcastReceiver](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and declare it in the AndroidManifest.xml.

Please refer to the following code snippet.

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver
    android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
<service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />
```

**Java code**

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

When GCM delivers a message to your device, `BroadcastReceiver` will receive the message and call the `onReceive()` function, wherein you may start a service to actually perform the intended task for you.

The above Code example uses a specialized `BroadcastReceiver` called `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, which makes sure that the device doesn't go to sleep, while the service is doing its work.

Refer to the Official Android Page for the same: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html

Comment: But it is not working in pre lollipop devices, it is working fine in lollipop devices.do i need to add any thing for pre lollipop devices.

Comment: Its not working for lenovo devices.. for other devices it works fine

Comment: It is also not working with MI phones,version android 6. Have any solution

Comment: For some phones, forcing a service to run in the background helps. Use AlarmManager to schedule a service when the app exits. This should make sure that the App process is alive and receivers listening to the broadcasts.

Comment: Hi, I am adding alarm manager in main activity. It work's fine in mi and Samsung devices but in VIVO and OPPO phones I don't get any notifications.

Comment: How can I do it on ionic 2?

Answer (score 18):

> When the app is closed forcelly by the user : notifications don't arrive

It's a feature of the Android platform. Force stopping an application by the user puts the application in a stopped state and none of its code is run, including any broadcast receivers declared in manifest. Only when the user explicitly launches the app it is put in a state where the receivers get fired.

For further reading: http://www.doubleencore.com/2014/06/effects-android-application-termination/

Comment: Is there any method to notify users such that you cannot receive notification until app open,since for e.g. autostart manager disable app on install. So GCM Push not working.

Comment: Its ok..if the notification don't arrive when app is closed. But when the app is launched again I didn't get those notification. Is it permanently lost?

Comment: @yuen shi: yes . When your app is closed still GCM push message deliver to your device. becouse of force closed app you don't get any notification.

Comment: Then how does it work for whatsapp app and other chat apps?

Comment: I ain't sure, but Whatsapp and other apps must have maintained some status(like sent, delivered, read) of the messages received by the app user. They would set the status accordingly.
Suppose if a message was sent to the device the status of that message would be "sent". If the message was not yet delivered to the application due to some reason, then status would remain "sent". Now the server identifies this status and sends again this message. When delivered to the app, they would set it's status as "delivered".

Comment: WhatsApp and similar probably use the SyncAdapter registered in the Accounts panel to perform some task when the app is force closed.

Comment: That is not correct. The services for notifications etc continue to run after the app has been closed.

Answer (score 11):

After some testing I did on this issue, I found out that it behaves differently on how the app is closed. If you close the app while the cable is connected to the device, it then blocks every notification when the app is closed.
However, if you take the cable off the device and close the app, when you send the notification, everything works again, as it should!

In case you get a "Waiting for the Debugger" popup message, just restart the device and then send a test notification!

Comment: I'm going to give more details on this: If you're debugging the app, the notifications will work at first. Then if you close the app (swipe from recent), they won't work. You must then re-launch the app once manually from the device (not by debugging). You can close it then and notification will arrive. It looks like when you close a debugging app, all of its services are stopped. I lost 2 days because of this.

Answer (score 8):

Firebase API has two types of messages, they call them:

- notification
- data

find more information from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages)

**IMPORTANT :** You can't send data payload messages from **Firebase Console**, Console only delivers notification message. So I have mentioned how to send push notification using postman please follow below steps for that.

You must send push messages with data payload because of data payload - Doesn't matter whether your application is in the foreground or background or killed, these messages will always be delivered to **onMessageReceived()** method.

In **Android 8.0 Oreo** if the application is closed, then notification is not received It is because of DOZE mode and battery optimization,you just have to turn off battery optimization for all apps or particular app.

Turn off battery optimization for your app by below step:

**Settings>> Battery >> battery Optimization >> find your app >> select >> if optimized click on don't optimize >> try pushing notification**

Send push notification using **postman**

Step 1: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

Step 2: Set this two into **Header**

**Authorization** : key=AIzaSyBuRl1Ikz3VXFvU7xW9mmg51lJ3uDSH

**Content-Type**  : application/json

Step 3: Send this json

```
{
 "to" : "eb9HgFulyzU:APA91bFMLReWWwilNFfJ1fnXZ0A2PhJAYsabg-UcK_dHgHQcstTzcxLs4_mqgOmZtUiyLMne4JaOG7f8KH7pWxB7JugOGCCYgjd4fUynRBKZvNUgjaj2UdJB2Ux8VocszuUydCX",
 "data" : {
     "message" : "First Notification",
     "title": "Push Notification",
     "key_1" : "Key 1 value",
     "key_2" : "Hello"
 }
}
```

Hope this helps..

Enjoy :) :)

Comment: So bascially, we need to send 'Data' payload for the messaging to work. Why the hell doesn anyone want 'Notification' payload then? Its utter useless if app must be opened to receive notifications

Comment: Your advice about the battery settings is CRUCIAL. I've read a million pieces of advice on how you have to configure the json, but it turns out, at least for me, the problem was battery settings all along.

Answer (score 6):

It will not work on killing the app from task manager, but work if you just slide it away from recent. I tried doing on whatsapp by killing it and ask someone to send a msg to me, and I haven't got any notification. Then I started the app, and I got notification.

Comment: I don't receive notification even if I slide it away from recent apps on some devices like Xiaomi. There is an "Autostart" feature in these phones and if I enable autostart for my app then I receive push notification even if I slide the app away from recent apps. But I don't want the user to manually enable the autostart for my app. There are other apps like whatsapp, facebook who have autostart enabled already. How should I do enable the autostart automatically when the app installs?

Comment: @NiteshKhatri Sorry, no clue about autostart.

Comment: i am also fetching same issue in huawei phone. Actually, it didn't getting any notification when app is cleared from task list. Actually it kill the app when we do this. Have you find any solution?

Comment: @Md.SajedulKarim That doesn't seem like normal behavior. Clearing app from recent should not kill app (tho any app can be killed by OS in case of low memory, but I don't think it will happen as soon as you slide it away).  I will say there is something wrong with the device OS (maybe vendor's fault)

Answer (score 2):

I just finished a GCM app.
It still works well if you close the app. The thing is you should have already opened the app for once.
create two class to achieve this goal: `GcmBroadcastReceiver` and `GcnIntentService`.
Find more information 
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Here is the trick

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
    // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
}
```

the class being extended is `WakeFulBroadcastReceiver`. There is a WAKE_LOCK permission in your Manifest.xml. 
    This allows using `PowerManager` `WakeLocks` to keep processor from sleeping or screen from dimming.
However, if you extend `BroadcastReceiver`, it will not work after the app is closed.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: But it is not working in pre lollipop devices, it is working fine in lollipop devices.do i need to add any thing for pre lollipop devices?

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying another phone and the second worked perfectly, even when the phone was off. The first had a room that did not allow to be notified when the app was closed ... 
Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue on Oneplus phone. As mentioned by many people above, the issue was forceful app termination. In my case, it was done due to "Recent App management" setting as shown below. Once I changed it to "Normal clear" setting everything started working fine.

[image]