# GCM background service: Enable application automattically in ASUS’s ZenFone 2 Auto-Start Manager?

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, background-process

I have integrated GCM in my application.but when i tested in ASUS’s ZenFone 2 Lollipop version after closing the app by swiping ie , in background state the GCM push notification couldn't receive.i have surfed about this and i saw about the [Auto-Start Manager](http://androidcommunity.com/asuss-auto-start-manager-app-explained-saves-battery-life-and-ram-20151020/) and after i set "Allow" my app in ASM then it works fine.

**Manifest**

```
  <!-- [START gcm_permission] -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="<package_name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission android:name="<package_name>.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <!-- [END gcm_permission] -->


    <!-- GCM Service -->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="<package_name>" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".gcm.GcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".gcm.InstanceIDListenerService"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name=".gcm.RegistrationIntentService"
        android:exported="false" />
```

But I'm afraid the awareness of a normal user about it.any way to overcome this worry ? how to prevent my app deny from the "ASM" ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313539/push-notifications-when-app-is-closed

Comment: Same problem here!!! The problem for me is with Huawei and Asus Phone

Comment: Same problem as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38843579/set-allow-permission-by-default-in-asus-auto-start-manager-from-code