# receiving push notifications when app is closed in xamarin

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to process GCM push notifications in Xamarin when the app is completely closed. Following the Xamarin Push Notifications tutorial I'm able to receive remote/push notifications from GCM, but as soon as I close the app I don't receive. Here's what I've tried so far:

1.Broadcast receiver:

```
    public class MyGCMBroadcastReceiver : BroadcastReceiver {

    public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        Intent gcmListenerServiceIntent = new Intent(context,typeof(MyGcmListenerService));
        Console.WriteLine ("Starting Broadcast Receiver...");
        context.StartService (gcmListenerServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

2. Manifest:

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
   <uses-permission android:name="za.co.snappyhome.snappy.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PRIVILEGED" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
   <application android:label="My App" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
   <receiver android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
             android:exported="true"
       android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
       <intent-filter>
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
           <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
           <category android:name="za.co.myapp.app" />
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   <receiver android:name="MyApp.Droid.Notifications.MyGCMBroadcastReceiver">
       <intent-filter>
          <actionandroid:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>                  
       </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
   </application>
   ```
3. GCMListenerService:

   ```
   [Service (Exported = false), IntentFilter (new [] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
   public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
   {

   public override void OnMessageReceived (string from, Bundle data)
   {
       if (data.ContainsKey ("data")) {

           if (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current != null) {
               String json = data.GetString("data");

               MessagingCenter.Send<Xamarin.Forms.Application, string> (Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current,
                   "NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE_RECEIVED", json);                 
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   }

I'm still getting to grips with Xamarin and GCM notifications, so my understanding might be wrong. My understanding is that I can start up broadcast receiver when the app boots. That will in-turn start a service that can listen to push notifications(in my case MyGcmListenerService). My first issue is that the broadcast receiver doesn't start on application boot (following this answer: [Trying to start a service on boot on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android)). Secondly, is it possible to invoke  MyGcmListenerService in order to start listening to notifications like what I'm trying to do. I've tried using GCMIntentService, but that seems to have been deprecated sometime ago: 
[Push Notifications when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313539/push-notifications-when-app-is-closed)

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I used the below configuration and piece of code with Xamarin Native - Android and could see the notifications when the app is closed.

1. Android manifest.xml

   ```
   <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver" android:exported="false" />
           <receiver android:name="com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver" android:exported="true" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                   <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                   <category android:name="${applicationId}" />
               </intent-filter>
           </receiver>

   <service android:name="HEET.Droid.ViewController.Login.FireBaseIIDService" android:permission="false" android:stopWithTask="false">
               <intent-filter>
                   <action android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging_event" />
               </intent-filter>
           </service>
   ```

   2. FireBaseIIDService.cs

As per latest version , In the FireBaseIIDService intent service class,
         onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage msg) will be invoked on receiving every message.

```
        [Service]
        [IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" })]
        public class FireBaseIIDService : FirebaseMessagingService{

   public override void OnMessageReceived (RemoteMessage msg) {
Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this, "my_notification_channel");
            builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.circle);
            var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(DashboardActivity));
            intent.AddFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
            builder.SetContentIntent(pendingIntent);
            builder.SetLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Resources, Resource.Drawable.circle));
            builder.SetContentTitle(Header);
            builder.SetContentText(body);
            builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound);
            builder.SetAutoCancel(true);
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)GetSystemService(NotificationService);
            notificationManager.Notify(1, builder.Build());
    }
    }
```

Comment: The sample I am following is C#/ Xamarin otherwise identical to this as far as I can see, but it definitely does NOT deliver the notiification if the app has been stopped, only foreground and background. Any ideas?

Comment: I am able to receive notifications when the app is packaged in release mode while in debug mode even i am not able to receive if the app is stopped.

Comment: Nice tip but unfortunately having just tried that the results don't change for me - still cannot receive notifications in the system tray once the app has been force stopped

Comment: Please post your code details.I will check if i would help you with my logic i built

Comment: Thanks - see existing thread here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57824810/xamarin-forms-android-not-receiving-push-notifications-when-closed/57851121?noredirect=1#comment102159402_57851121