# GCM Broadcast receiver not detcting gcm notification when the app is closed

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-messaging, broadcastreceiver

I have a broadcast receiver which detects oncoming notifications when the app is open and in background but when the recent app is cleared the receiver is not working please suggest me ideas.

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver { 

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        try {
            json.putOpt("userid", StorePreference.GetSharedPreferenceDetails(context, "memberid"));
            json.putOpt("rid",StorePreference.GetSharedPreferenceDetails(context, "partnerid"));
            json.putOpt("message", "Received");
            BoundService.getInstance().onlinestatus(json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Manifest decleration:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.twogether.receivers.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
    android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
      <intent-filter>
       <action android:name = "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
       <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
      </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: post your manifest. just want to check how you defined receiver

Comment: What version of GCM is this? You should be using a GcmListenerService instead of a BroadcastReceiver

Comment: @krishna i have added the manifest

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314088/4049612](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24314088/4049612)  Check this example

Comment: @TimCastelijns i need to detect gcm notifications even at background ...

Comment: on which device you are testing this app

Comment: did u got any solution for this? I do facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to register your receiver in manifest, use GcmListenerService to receive messages.

google example https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services has example to do this.

```
    <!-- gcm_receiver, this is android source-->
    <receiver
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.myapp.gcm" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <!-- gcm_listener service -->
    <service
        android:name="com.qblinks.qmote.GcmListenerService"
        android:exported="false" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

// Use this service to receive message

```
public class GcmListenerService extends com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmListenerService {
    public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
        String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.v(TAG, "From: " + from);
        Log.v(TAG, "Message: " + message);
        sendNotification(message);
}

private void sendNotification(String message) {

    Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
            .setContentTitle("this is title")
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))//multi line
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri); // ring or vibrate if no ring
    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(Const.NOTIFICATION_GCM /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

When the app is close you need to wake the app up, means you need to have the permission to do that

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and after you can set:

```
AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        manager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000, yourIntent);
```