# Push notification is not showing when app is closed

Tags: android

Push notification is not showing when the app is closed(i.e,not present in foreground or background) Getting the following error code in log

```
 W/BroadcastQueue: Reject to launch app com.nexhop.dev.debug/10129 for broadcast: App Op 63
W/GCM-DMM: broadcast intent callback: result=CANCELLED forIntent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10000000 pkg=com.nexhop.dev.debug (has extras) }
```

But the notification is showing few phones like samsung galaxy. I am using FCM for sending notification.

Please give any suggestion to fix this issue?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Could it be the `WAKE_LOCK` permission is not defined? Make sure you have all the permissions implemented for push notifications

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

<permission
    android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="${applicationId}.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

> When the app is closed forcelly by the user : notifications don't
>   arrive

It's a feature of the Android platform. Force stopping an application by the user puts the application in a stopped state and none of its code is run, including any broadcast receivers declared in manifest. Only when the user explicitly launches the app it is put in a state where the receivers get fired.

[Thread@laalto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313539/push-notifications-when-app-is-closed)

**Upate:**

can be possible solution you can hide your app from recent so your cant swipe it and your app will be able to receive the notification.

Comment: this feature is added in latest API

Comment: but it's not working in my phone ASUS Zenfone 2 with android 6.0.let me know more helpful answers

Comment: yes it will not work in 6.0 m dam sure. here is all details https://possiblemobile.com/2014/06/effects-android-application-termination/   and this post help consider tick mark.

Comment: It's possible in asus phone by enabling the auto start for the app from auto start manager.And in Xiaomi need to goto settings->battery & performance->choose app->then click on No restrictions.

Comment: I am getting the notification,It's working perfectly

Comment: Then FB notification getting displayed when the app is closed