# Not receive notification when mobile is lock

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using FCM.
When mobile screen is ON , Notifications received by all mobiles ( In my case , there is 12 mobiles )
When mobile is locked , Notification send by server successfully but not receive by mobile

Comment: Your application may not designed to get notification at background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39756330/android-background-notifications-with-firebase-cloud-messaging-not-received Maybe this will help you

Comment: Check if this helps. http://stackoverflow.com/a/38795553/1840795

Comment: No , background scenario is work perfectly...Thanks for helping... I have got the soluation...In Server It should be  "delayWhileIdle(false)" instead of "delayWhileIdle(true)"

Comment: Hey @himali Thank you very much for this solution, you saved me a lot of time, I was going crazy because I did not find the right solution: D.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Permission in manifest which prevents your phone from sleeping.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
```

also check in latest device their  is concept of protected apps only protected app will run in background only these apps will receive notification when device is locked

In protected apps located in 
Advanced settings->Battery manager->protected aps

Comment: I have add this permission already in manifest...Thanks for helping... I have got the soluation...In Server It should be  "delayWhileIdle(false)" instead of "delayWhileIdle(true)"

Comment: In server means?

Comment: @himali I'd like to know how you fixed it.

Comment: The delay_while_idle key specifies if you want to send the push message when the device is idle. By setting the key to true, the push message will not be delivered to the device until the device becomes active. so while creating a notification using this in payload `{"delay_while_idle": false}`