# Push notifications are not delivered to app until the user unlock screen

Tags: android, push-notification

we use the old GCM HTTP server to send push notifications to the app.

when they are received in the app we use the notification builder to show the message:

```
 NotificationChannel mChannel = new NotificationChannel(
            "com.....app.notification", "...",
            android.app.NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
        mChannel.setShowBadge(true);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(mChannel);

        mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, mChannel.getId());

 mBuilder.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setContentTitle(fromHtml(title))
            .setTicker(fromHtml(title))
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
...
mNotificationManager.notify(appName, notId, mBuilder.build());
```

all works well, except that on some devices, the push are delivered, only when the user unlocks the screen.

i know that there are several android settings that might allow this or not.
but they are too complex and no user could possibly find all of them.

so my question is:
is there a way to programaticaly make sure that the push are always shown?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41095299/not-receive-notification-when-mobile-is-lock

Comment: why are you passing timestamp in setWhen()? As you have to show the notification immediately, you shouldn't use this.

Comment: Also, I think @Rohit5k2 is pointing to the right solution.

Comment: android.permission.WAKE_LOCK is already there

Comment: can it be because we use GCM instead of the new FCM?

Comment: it works better with FCM