# php android push notifications set high priority

Tags: php, android, push-notification

I am sending notifications from the browser using PHP to an android device. when I start app after logout notifications are coming but if I kill app notifications are not coming. any solution for this.

```
 public function send_android($target, $fields) {
    $apiKey = 'XXXXXXXXX';
    $headers = array("Content-Type:" . "application/json", "Authorization:key=" . $apiKey);

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
     curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Push Notifications when app is closed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313539/push-notifications-when-app-is-closed)

Answer (score 2):

You need to send extra key in fields array named `"priority"` and value will "`high`".
So your fields array will be same as ...

```
$fields = array('to' => $token, 'notification' => $notification,'priority'=>'high');
```