# Notification not receive when Application terminated in android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use firebase push notification to device token. When app is opening or in foreground I can get notification well. But when app is kill or clear app on current task, I cannot receive notification send.

I have tried on onMessageReceived aleardy at first time work. but now it's not work when killed app.

- Code  Receive Notification:

  ```
  class MyFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
        override fun onMessageReceived(p0: RemoteMessage) {
            val data = p0!!.data
            Log.e("AAAAAAAAAAAAA: ","data 
            111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111:" + data["key1"])
       }
  }
  ```
- Post Send notification data:
  Send to:  https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
- Data   :

  ```
  {
  "to" : "token key",
  "data": {
         "key1" : "value1",
         "key2" : "value2",
         "other_key" : true
       }
  }
  ```

Result, for app is opening, I can receive data well, but when killed I cannot receive data.

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24313539/push-notifications-when-app-is-closed

Comment: Did you follow [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)? According to it, you only need to handle notifications while in foreground. Background notifications comes for free if everything is configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending data to 
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
you're using the legacy http protocol as you can see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

This is not very clear in documentation.

In this protocol to receive the data message when app is in background or closed you should use this payload:

```
{
"to" : "token key",
"data": {
       "key1" : "value1",
       "key2" : "value2",
       "other_key" : true
     },
"priority" : 10,
"time_to_live" : 60
}
```

Test first with maximum priority (10) and then downgrade according t your needs. Also adjust time_to_live in seconds according to your needs.